# How to control users, requests and throughput in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm performing a load test on my server using JMeter 5.4.1. I want to use 3 users who will be sending requests at 10 TPS which means 10 requests would be sent to the server per second. I'm already using the Concurrency thread group and Shaping Throughput Timer but confused with the configuration-like difference between target concurrency and no. of users I need to pass. I tried giving 3 in the target concurrency textbox but throughput was very low than expected. After increasing the target concurrency, I started getting the desired throughput. So I just need clarity on the configuration of the Concurrency Thread Group.

**I just want to know what configuration I  need to do to achieve 10 TPS by using 3 users in Jmeter**?

**Note**: Using Jmeter 5.4.1

Comment: observe your app response time, your TPS will depend on it. so that you can set your desired number of threads to generate 10 TPS.

Answer (score 0):

Your average response time needs to be `333ms` to get `10 TPS` using `3 threads`, if your average response time is `1 second` then you will need to increase the number of threads to `10` to get `10TPS`.

So you need to measure the average response time of all your requests in the JMeter test plan, then you will be able to decide the number of threads to get your desired TPS.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) allows you to specify the number of threads (virtual users)

   By default each thread (virtual user) will be executing Samplers as fast as it can, according to JMeter's thread model the user will wait for response from the previous sampler before starting the next one
2. [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) allows you to specify number of requests per second, however you should have **sufficient amount of threads** in order to reach/maintain the desired concurrency.

You can reach 10 TPS with 3 users **only if response time of your application for a single sampler will be equal or less than 300 milliseconds**, larger response times - proportionally lower TPS.

So if your application response time is above 300 milliseconds you will need to add more users either in the Concurrency Thread Group or via the [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) which is capable of detecting the current throughput and automatically add extra threads if the current amount is not enough in order to reach/maintain the target throughput

More information: [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin)